# Getting Only Custom Post Types Posts with WP_Query

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to get custom posts with WP_Query but it's not returning only custom post type posts but also default posts too.

I am using

```
$args = array (
    'post_type' => array ('survey')
);
$sPosts = new WP_Query($args);
```

as a result I am getting 'survey' posts as well as default posts, I only need it to return 'survey' posts.

P.S. when I use `query_posts()` it returns the required result, but just not getting it done with WP_Query and I prefer to use `WP_Query` not the `query_posts()`

Comment: Do you have other custom queries on the same page. `pre_get_posts` might also be the culprit here. Also +1 for not reverting to `query_posts` as an alternative

Comment: thx for reply, No other custom query on the page, even it's the only query I executing on the index page.

Answer (score 0):

Please try it like that....

> ```
> <?php
>     $new = new WP_Query('post_type=discography');
>     while ($new->have_posts()) : $new->the_post();
>      the_content();
>     endwhile;
> ?>
> ```

Comment: I mentioned that I want to do with WP_Query, with query_posts() it's already working.

Comment: You should **never** make use of `query_posts`. It breaks the main query and pagination. -1 for not reading the question

Comment: Please try the updated code...might be it will help you.

Comment: Please check this link too for more help....It will also help you.
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-posts-type-with-custom-taxonomy-wp_query-1

Comment: Tried again with no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe this custom query should actually be your main query, in which case you should not use a custom query

The problem you are facing is either due to

- Wrong use somewhere of `pre_get_posts`. Remember, `pre_get_posts` alters **all** instances of `WP_Query`, backend and front end. Lack of correct use will break all queries
- You have not changed the loop to be objects of your new query

To come back to the point, as said, this is suppose to be the main query, so lets target that problem.

The first thing to do would be to delete the custom query. Once you have done this, you would only see normal post.

We are now going to use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query to only show custom posts. Paste the following **inside your functions.php**

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q ) {
    if( !is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() && $q->is_home() ) {
        $q->set( 'post_type', 'YOUR CPT' );
    }
});
```

You should now just see post from your cpt on the homepage

**EDIT**

Your index.php should look something like this

```
if( have_posts() ) {
    while( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();

        // HTML mark up and template tags like the_title()

    }
}else{

    echo 'No posts found';

}
```

Comment: I used it with loop object without success, and also I have no where pre_get_posts setup, actually I have nothing in functions.php as it's just a blank theme and just started to convert it.

Comment: Check my update. The `pre_get_posts` part should be inside your functions.php. I have posted an example on how index.php should look like

Comment: Any feedback on this

Answer (score 0):

**This code can get all the posts in a custom post type..,**

*wp_query is the function can get all the posts in the custom post type. wp_query requires array, so you can give the custom post type name in post id to array*

```
$args = array(

            'post_type' => 'address',    //custom post type
            'posts_per_page' => -1       // get all posts

         );

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// Check that we have query results.

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {   

    // Start looping over the query results.

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {

       $query->the_post();

       echo( get_the_title() );

    }

}
```